# DES key complementation property

Tags: keys, brute-force-attack, des

It is known that DES has the *key-complementation property*. That is, given any key $k$ and any
message $m\in\{0,1\}^{64}$
$$\operatorname{DES}_k(m)=\overline{\operatorname{DES}_\overline k(\overline m)}$$

By using this property, show that the key search of DES can be sped up by a factor of two.

Comment: I'll guess, but you should verify, that means swap 1 to 0 and 0 to 1.

Comment: Give a look of Fact 7.87 of the Handbook of Applied Cryptography: http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap7.pdf

Comment: Note: By definition $\overline x$ is the bitwise complement or [bitwise NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) of $x$. $\;$ Hint: assume that you can obtain the ciphertexts for two values of plaintext: an $m$ that you know [that is: you obtain $m$ and $c=\operatorname{DES}_k(m)$ ], and an $m′$ that you choose [that is: you choose $m′$ and obtain $c′=\operatorname{DES}_k(m′)$ ]. How do you choose $m′$ so that you can test (with low odds of false positive) two values of $k$ with a single DES encryption?

Comment: Is this a question or a command?

Comment: Exercise 4 Complementation Property of DES https://courses.cs.ut.ee/2011/crypto1/www/tutorial/Tutorial1.pdf https://courses.cs.ut.ee/2011/crypto1/www/tutorial/Tutorial1_sol.pdf